# Tagging and misspellings

Tags: php, symfony, tagging, misspelling

I'm going to be implementing tagging soon via http://knpbundles.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle. This system will allow users to tag themselves and other content (much the way you see it done all over the internet these days).

I am wondering if anyone knows any good methods to reduce misspellings in tags? O should I simply allow them to exist because they will naturally filter out?

Edit: I'm curious why the downvote, I have already searched Google and SO, no one has addressed misspellings in a system like this. How is this not a valid question?

Comment: Suggestive combo-boxes are an option here.

Comment: I plan to use that already, but we do that for things like Job Title and we still get tons of misspellings etc, I'm sure there may be some level of manual cleaning that has to be done, but I'm curious for those who have build such systems if spelling has ever been considered or if it simply was not a factor

Comment: It appears many simply must do it manually: https://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-handle-misspelled-tags-in-their-topic-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there really is no way to curb misspellings except to allow users to moderate and/or have admins moderating.

https://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-handle-misspelled-tags-in-their-topic-database